# Set Browser Mode to IE 8 automatically when html page gets loaded

Tags: internet-explorer-8, compatibility

My Application is compatible only with IE8.So, whenever we open the page,**Broswer Mode** should set automatically to IE 8,instead of going to **developer tools** and setting there

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to simply fix your app?

Answer (score 1):

I always use

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" >
```

this needs to get in the head tag.

Comment: what is the difference .. content="IE=8" and content="IE=EmulateIE8"

Comment: i think ie8 just changes the browser mode, where emulate changes both document and broswer mode

Comment: <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" > is not working .Also "IE=8" is changing only document mode not browser mode

Comment: Its from the docs, Im not sure why its not working http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Madhan - IE=8 means IE8 standards mode only.  EmulateIE8 means IE8 standards mode or IE5 quirks mode (if the document triggers quirks mode).  You also have to make sure the meta tag is the very first tag in the head, or second if you are using a charset declaration.  Anything else will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a meta tag to your document head specifying [IE8 compatibility mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8" >
```